# Abrir una App propia desde otra en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

Estoy haciendo una App que trabaja como launcher de otras Apps. Una de las opciones es abrir una App propia de una calculadora pasándole un parámetro de tipo texto mediando un EditText para que se muestre en la misma. Supongo que para pasarle ese parametro tendré que hacerlo con un intent y haciendo un putExtra al campo de la otra App donde quiero que se muestre, el problema radica en que no se como abrir esa App. Tengo otros dos botones que abren Apps del propio dispositivo y funcionan correctamente pero no se como abrir una creada por mi y pasarle ese parámetro. Llevo un rato dandole vueltas, mirando documentación y tal pero no me aclaro. Si pudierais ayudarme los agradecería ya que es lo único que me falta para terminar esta App. Adjunto el código de la clase Java.

```
    package com.dani.actividadesrelacionadas;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
        String url;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button botonFotos = findViewById(R.id.botonFotos);
            botonFotos.setOnClickListener(this);
            botonFotos.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
            Button botonNavegador = findViewById(R.id.botonNavegador);
            botonNavegador.setOnClickListener(this);
            botonNavegador.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
            Button botonCalculadora = findViewById(R.id.botonCalculadora);
            botonCalculadora.setOnClickListener(this);
            botonCalculadora.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.botonFotos:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.botonNavegador:
                    try {
                        EditText campoNavegador = findViewById(R.id.url);
                        url = campoNavegador.getText().toString();
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent2);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No se ha podido abrir la URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.botonCalculadora: //AQUI ES DONDE TENGO EL PROBLEMA
                    EditText campoCalculadora = findViewById(R.id.textoCalculadora);
                    String textoCalculadora = campoCalculadora.getText().toString();
    
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Abrir otra aplicaciòn Android desde tu aplicaciòn.**

Lo recomendable para abrir otra aplicaciòn es un Intent usando el id del paquete con el mètodo `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( )`:

```
String applicationId = "com.domain.myapp";
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationId
```

Tambièn puedes detectar en caso de que no exista la aplicaciòn en tu dispositivo, abrir Google Play para instalarla.

```
   String applicationId = "com.domain.openotherapp";
    try{
        startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationId));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + applicationId)));
    }
```

Otra forma es usando la clase `ComponentName` :

```
  String applicationId = "com.domain.openotherapp";
        try{
            ComponentName name=new ComponentName(applicationId,
                    applicationId + ".MainActivity");
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            intent.setComponent(name);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + applicationId)));
        }
```

Pero es **muy importante definir el nombre del paquete de la aplicaciòn a abrir dentro de  `<queries>` en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`** ya que le darà permisos para poder abrir desde tu aplicaciòn.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jorgesys.myapp1">

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.domain.openotherapp" />
    </queries>

    <application...
```