# Abrir otra app si esta instalada - No me detecta la app como instalada

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.android

Tengo un método que revisa si la app de Disney Plus, Netflix, HBO y Amazon Prime están instaladas para luego abrir la que se seleccione. Si la app esta instalada me la debería abrir, de lo contrario me lleva a un URL especifico.

La de Disney funciona, las demás no. Ya revise el nombre del paquete de la Play Store, pero no logro encontrar el error (Cabe mencionar que las tengo todas instaladas)

**Codigo de Disney+ que funciona correctamente:**

```
private static bool IsDisneyPlusAppInstalled()
        {
            try
            {
                // Intent para verificar si la aplicación de Disney+ está instalada
                Application.Context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo("com.disney.disneyplus", PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
                return true;
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**El de Netflix que no funciona:**

```
private static bool IsNetflixAppInstalled()
        {
            try
            {
                // Intent para verificar si la aplicación de Netflix está instalada
                Application.Context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo("com.netflix.mediaclient", PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
                return true;
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Desde Android 11 (nivel de API 30), algunas app instaladas no son "visibles" de forma predeterminada. Debes de indicar explícitamente el paquete que quieres "ver" en tu app. En el `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.netflix.mediaclient"/>
        <package android:name="com.hbo.otraCosa"/>
        <package android:name="com.amazon.otraCosa"/>
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu app se orienta a Android 11 (nivel de API 30) debes revisar acerca de la **[Visibilidad de paquetes](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility?hl=es-419)**

> Si conoces el conjunto específico de apps a las que quieres realizar
> consultas o con las que quieres interactuar (como las que se integran
> con tu app o aquellas cuyos servicios usas), incluye los nombres en un
> conjunto de elementos `<package>` dentro del elemento `<queries>`:

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.disney.disneyplus" />
        <package android:name="com.netflix.mediaclient" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

El método quedaría de esta forma:

```
   private void LaunchNetflixAppOrWeb(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                String applicationId = "com.netflix.mediaclient";
                
                    Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationId);
                    if (intent != null)
                    {
                        StartActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OpenWebBrowser("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + applicationId);
                    }
            }
```

Revisa esta pregunta relacionada:

**[Abrir una App propia desde otra en Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499542/abrir-una-app-propia-desde-otra-en-android-studio?rq=1)**

Comment: Gracias Jorge. El método me quedo de la siguiente forma, por favor añádelo a tu respuesta para que quede completa:

Comment: private void LaunchNetflixAppOrWeb(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String applicationId = "com.netflix.mediaclient";
            
                Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationId);
                if (intent != null)
                {
                    StartActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    OpenWebBrowser("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + applicationId);
                }

Comment: @KennyAli listo